# Should I stop taking my prenatal vitamins?

Tags: pregnancy

I bought what I thought were the best quality prenatal vitamins. They are $100 a bottle and manufactured by Bayer pharmaceuticals in Germany. However, I was shocked by the list of excipients:

"Each tablet contains macrogol, glycerol distearate, gelatin, cellulose, sodium starch glycollate,povidone, lactose, mannitol, magnesium stearate, ethylcellulose, hypromellose, talc, titanium dioxide, iron oxide yellow."

Not all of these are bad, for example gelatin, cellulose, lactose, etc.  But I'm worried about the others...

I'm thinking that I might use a nutritional tracking program to ensure that I'm getting the pregnancy RDI of B12, Iron, folate,iodine and calcium from my diet. The other nutrients are quite easy to obtain from a healthy diet

I'm in the second trimester 24 weeks to be precise

Comment: A side note on supplements - they're not regulated the way medicines are (magnesium could be 40% magnesium, 60% skull dust). Just because it's $100 a bottle doesn't mean you can't get the same thing for $12 at walgreens. Or as you seem to be doing, getting much of it through healthy consumption of the right foods (the natural and best way to get your vitamins). I don't have an official take on the subject other than to suggest you explore the full nature of ingredients (like gelatin) - and decide for yourself if the same goal can't be achieved in a more delicious, less revolting way.

Comment: Here's a little info on supplement regulation: http://www.cancer.org/treatment/treatmentsandsideeffects/complementaryandalternativemedicine/dietarysupplements/dietary-supplements-fda-regulations

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I realize that supplements aren't regulated, that's why I bought these, because they're manufactured by a wellknown pharmaceutical company and only available from a pharmacy. I don't have any reason to believe that they contain anything additional to what's listed on the label, I also believe the dosages are correct. This is why I don't want to switch to another unregulated prenatal supplement. But the declared excipients are quite worrying.

Comment: What does your doctor or midwife have to say about this -- was a medical professional the one who suggested prenatal vitamins in the first place?

Comment: Hi Erica, my doctor suggested these pills (Brand name 'Elevit')  but then again doctors don't care about the side effects of drugs. He probably thinks that the benefit outweighs the risk. This might be true for an unhealthy person who eats junk food all the time, but my diet is generally pretty good so I can probably get these nutrients from diet alone

Comment: If you bring up the side effects of the vitamin additives and whether you'll be able to get the same nutrients from a balanced diet, your doctor should have some thoughts on the matter. If you're not satisfied with his feedback, find a different medical professional to help you with your pregnancy -- seriously, if I didn't trust somebody to give me reasonable feedback on my pregnancy diet needs, I certainly wouldn't trust him during the delivery process!

Comment: How are you choosing which vitamins and nutrients you're going to track, and why such a small list? For instance, [Vitamin D insufficiency in pregnancy may be associated with "reduced bone-mineral accrual" in the child](http://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(06)67922-1/abstract?cc=y=) when measured as far out as 9 years old.

Comment: Hi CreationEdge, The program that I use tracks all vitamins, minerals, macronutrients, amino acids, omega 3, etc.  (Cron-o-meter based on the USDA database). I didn't list vitamin D because it would be easier to obtain it through sunlight in the summer and liquid vitamin D3 supplement in the winter (only other ingredient being coconut oil). I listed those nutrients because the other nutrients (like vitamin A, C, B vitamins are relatively easy to obtain from a healthy diet - I have tracked my diet before). I tend to be deficient in B12 so I plan to continue monthly blood tests for that.

Comment: Generally most nutrients are easy to obtain through a healthy diet. The ones I want to focus on are iodine (deficient in the soil in my country), B12 (I don't absorb it well), iron (hard to get from food unless consciously choosing high iron foods), folate (reduces risk of premature birth), calcium (to reduce my own risk of osteoporosis in the future). Also DHA

Comment: "but then again doctors don't care about the side effects of drugs" citation needed. This is a pretty libellous thing to say.

Answer (score 7):

Excipients are not bad; they are necessary.

The idea of going off prenatal vitamins because of excipients seems a bit  like throwing the baby out with the bath water. There are definite risks to the baby which are ameliorated by supplementation. Folic acid is a water-soluble vitamin (you can't store it up) and it's unlikely you'll get the amount recommended for pregnant women every day by healthy eating. The same goes for the other supplements - not to address each one individually - but there is a reason for supplementation in pregnancy: the need is greater and the likelihood of your diet providing all those micronutrients is low.

In earlier days, excipients were considered inactive ingredients. However, they frequently have significant impact on the quality and efficacy of a drug (or vitamin supplement) in terms of dosages of a product. They modulate solubility, bioavailability, and stability of the drug, they maintain proper pH, act as antioxidants, binders, etc.

> ...doctors don't care about the side effects of drugs. He probably thinks that the benefit outweighs the risk.

First, of course doctors care deeply about the side effects of drugs. I'm unsure why you would think otherwise. That is the reason - in its entirety - that there even *exists* a risk to benefit ratio.

While it's true that the risk for neural tube defects may have passed, there are other reasons for continuing the supplement. And in pregnancy, the risk of not getting the micromutrients you need is greater than in the non-pregnant state, and they affect *two* people, of course, one of them growing and developing still.

If you are concerned about any of the agents in your vitamin formulation, you can Google them individually to look at their safety profiles. I think this is a better alternative to deciding based on guessing what may or may not be harmful to you and your baby.

> ...a nutritional tracking program to ensure that I'm getting the pregnancy RDI of B12, Iron, folate, iodine and calcium from my diet...

Because they are not considered drugs or pharmaceuticals, *excipients in food products* are often not listed. You may well be ingesting the same things unless you are eating only fresh fruits, vegetables/leafy greens, and freshly butchered meats.

<sub>[Excipient Development for Pharmaceutical, Biotechnology, and Drug Delivery Systems](https://adiyugatama.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/excipient-development-for-pharmaceutical-dosage-forms.pdf)</sub>

Comment: Hi anongoodnurse, you are totally right, it wouldn't be possible to make tablets without fillers. I completely realize that. I mean, I wouldn't mind if it was something like magneisum sterate and cellulose, etc.. but there are so many, and talc?? seriously?   I will google them individually, but it's very hard to find information establishing safety, especially during pregnancy. for this reason, it would be easier and safer for me to avoid the pills altogether. although, i'd have to be careful not to "throw the baby out with the bathwater" so I'd have to be extra good with my diet.

Comment: I don't think I need folate anymore, because I'm in the second trimester. I took separate folate pills during the first trimester, my ultrasound showed that the neural tube and brain was normal

Comment: even if the ingredients aren't harmful, i feel anxious about giving them to my baby. it's mostly just for my peace of mind, to be honest.

Comment: I mostly follow a paleo type diet, so I mostly do eat fresh fruits/vegetables/seafood/meats/eggs/dried fruit and nuts, etc...  .  However, I have added in grains - oats and rice  - to provide carbs and energy for the growing baby .

Comment: Thank you for your advice - I won't discontinue the pills for now, until I do some further research, and until I track my diet for a week to ensure that I'm meeting pregnancy RDI for all nutrients

Comment: Fresh fruits and leafy greens have plenty of fun things in them too, unless you're growing them yourself - even organic isn't a guarantee of perfectly pure produce.

Answer (score 2):

1) Do you have any clinical evidence that the fillers in the vitamins are dangerous in those amounts?

2) You are correct that the clinical evidence showing benefits to vitamin supplementation in healthy people is minimal at best.

3) However, folic acid for pregnant people is a major exception, clinical evidence shows a major drop in neural tube malformations when women get high levels of folic acid in the early weeks, and its possible that this level is very hard to get through diet alone.  If you know you are pregnant already, the critical window for that has likely closed, but if you are still trying, you should stick with folic acid supplementation, if nothing else.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4160020/

> Overall, the results are consistent in showing a protective effect of
>   daily folic acid supplementation (alone or in combination with other
>   vitamins and minerals) in preventing NTDs compared with no
>   interventions/placebo or vitamins and minerals without folic acid
>   (risk ratio (RR) 0.28, 95% confidence interval (CI) 0.15 to 0.52).

Comment: 1. I haven't seen any clinical evidence that shows that the fillers are dangerous, but I'd rather apply the precautionary principle. especially because chemicals can be dangerous to fetuses even when they have no effect on adults

Comment: 2. I believe that too, but the RDI increases so much during pregnancy that I'd have to be *perfect* with my eating habits (no room for empty calories). It's still possible though, using a nutrition tracker/computer program. but involves a lot of work.. such as keeping a food record, counting serving sizes, and entering them into the compute program and such

Comment: 3. I'm in the second trimester, so I don't think I need folic acid anymore as the neural tube would have closed by now.  However, the iodine content of the soil in my country is very low, so I'm just going to take an iodine tablet (manufactured by pharmaceutical company, not supplement) in order to prevent cognitive issues... also perhaps an omega 3 supplement.. but I'm still considering this, I might just eat 4x servings of low mercury oily fish instead each week... because the fish oil in supplements can be rancid

Comment: @Sara: have you considered algae to supplement iodine? I found a sheet of nori much easier to slip in somewhere than low-merc. fish.

Comment: Vitamins are chemicals.  "Avoiding chemicals" is not actually possible.  You might avoid tiny amounts of harmless excipients, and end up getting poisoned by natural E.coli toxin.